# Programmatically add a button with a macro to an Excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating formated worksheets with an Excel VBA application and I would like to add programmatically add a button to each worksheet when created. This button must have a macro attached to it, which display the average of the values in a certain range in a special cell, and change the background color of this cell depending on the value of the average. Is it possible to this, and if yes, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the Button like this or example:

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(52.5, 7.5, 173.25, 41.25).Select 'Arguments are coordinates
Selection.OnAction = "Button_Click"
```

Now make sure the `Button_Click` sub has the logic you want.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be fine, but apparently the macros are disabled in the worksheet I generate and the code inside the Button_Click sub doesn't execute when I click on the button, how can I programmatically enable the macros for each worksheet I create ?

Comment: You can't programmatically enable macros. What would be the point in this as a security feature :). You need to go to options and lower your level of security to enable macros by default.

Comment: @otus what's the error message and in which module is the `button_click` code located?

Comment: @Rory my bad then. Strange though.

Comment: @AnalystCave.com Not really - you have to have already enabled macros to run the code that then enables code in the relevant workbook, so it's not really a security flaw. ;)

Comment: @Rory the error message is :"It's impossible to run this macro. It is possible that it is not available in this workbook or that all macros are disabled". Actually I want to create a new Excel worksheet with this macro in it from another Excel macro, the code of `button_click` is located in a sub of a userform that I use to create new worksheets (PS: I translated the error message from french)

Comment: You can't assign a routine in a userform module to a button in a worksheet. It just won't work.

Comment: @Rory how can I do then ?

Comment: You need the macro to be in a normal module. Then you can use `.Onaction = "'workbook name.xlsm'!macro_name"` to call it.